# Store type information with DynamicObject

Tags: c#, dynamic, nullable, dynamicobject

I'm trying to design a process for doing extract transform load operations.  I want to use the ExpandoObject in my pipeline to allow me to easily add columns to my data stream.  Basically I read data from some kind of datasource cast it a dynamic and yield return it to a pipeline of transforms that add properties to it either based on existing properties or something else then stream it into a database.

The issue I have is that I need type information for all the properties I add to my expando object even if I add a Nullable type.  This is lost if the Nullable type is null because of the boxing of the value.  I want the type information so that at the end of my pipeline I can implement a datareader over my enumeration of ExpandoObjects and stream the data into a database.

I had hoped the SetMemberBinder.ReturnType property might help me but it seems to return an object.

here's some sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;

using Xunit

namespace Whanger
{
    public class MyExpando : DynamicObject
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Dictionary<string, Type> propertyTypes = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

        public Dictionary<string, Type> Types
        {
            get
            {
                return propertyTypes;
            }
        }

        public Dictionary<string, object> Values
        {
            get
            {
                return properties;
            }
        }

        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            if (properties.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
            {
                result = properties[binder.Name];
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                result = null;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
        {
            properties[binder.Name] = value;
            propertyTypes[binder.Name] = binder.ReturnType;//always object :(
            return true;
        }

        public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
        {
            dynamic method = properties[binder.Name];
            result = method(args[0].ToString(), args[1].ToString());
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class MyExpandoTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void CanAddDynamicMembers()
        {
            dynamic obj = new MyExpando();
            obj.Name = "Wibble";
            obj.Value = 2;

            Assert.Equal(obj.Name, "Wibble");
            Assert.Equal(obj.Value, 2);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void CanMaintainType()
        {
            dynamic obj = new MyExpando();
            int? nullableInt = null;
            obj.NullInt = nullableInt;
            obj.Name = "Wibble";
            Assert.Equal(obj.Name, "Wibble");
            Assert.Null(obj.NullInt);
            //fails
            Assert.Equal(typeof(int?), ((MyExpando)obj).Types["NullInt"]);


        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to find out the type from TrySetMember?  I wonder if there's some way to use some expression tree magic of something?

If anyone has any great ideas I'd love to hear them.  It all works well except for the nullable types but they are key for database operations.

Thanks

Comment: Although not explicitly mentioned, this might be of interest: [`System.Dynamic.ExpandObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: `ExpandoObject` is just a dictionary of objects, nullable struct will get boxed there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

I've done some research whether the type information is stored somewhere and I've discovered that during the time of setting the member, there is a `Func<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object,int?,object>` object being used. This is probably used to store the binding for later uses.

However, this cache is actually passed to the binder: private **`CallSiteBinder.Cache`** field. It contains an `IDictionary<Type,object>` that contains a type of the cache delegate as a key and the delegate itself. So, by examining the generic arguments for the delegate type, you can obtain the type of the expression that was used in the assignment.

Complete method:

```
private static readonly FieldInfo CallSiteBinder_Cache = typeof(CallSiteBinder).GetField("Cache", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
private static Type BindingType(CallSiteBinder binder)
{
    IDictionary<Type,object> cache = (IDictionary<Type,object>)CallSiteBinder_Cache.GetValue(binder);
    Type ftype = cache.Select(t => t.Key).FirstOrDefault(t => t != null && t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Func<,,,>));
    if(ftype == null) return null;
    Type[] genargs = ftype.GetGenericArguments();
    return genargs[2];
}
```

This method obtains the secret *Cache* dictionary and finds a *Type* key that is has been constructed from `Func<T1,T2,T3,TResult>`. Then is just extracts the type argument.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, but there's no general solution.  An `object` parameter can't detect whether the value passed was previously stored in a `Nullable<T>` variable.  It seems like you will have to wait until you have multiple records and see if there are a mix of `null` and values.

<strike>In the specific case here, I would check the `ReturnType` property on the `binder` parameter and see if that tells you what you need.</strike> I see you already checked that.

Your general problem is that all you have is the value and its type, not the static type of the expression.  For example, you can't distinguish these cases either:

```
string s = "hello";
object o = s;
dynamo.P = s; // case 1
dynamo.P = o; // case 2
```

or even

```
dynamo.Use(s);
dynamo.Use(o);
```

This is *very* different from statically-typed languages, where the type of an expression is used in overload resolution.  It looks like that sort of thing just isn't possible with `DynamicObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you add an overload:

```
public override bool TrySetMember<T>(SetMemberBinder binder, Nullable<T> value)
{
    properties[binder.Name] = value;
    propertyTypes[binder.Name] = typeof(Nullable<T>);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You can't override unless there is a base class method to override.  Note that in the provided code, there are no explicit calls to `TrySetMember`, only ones synthesized by the compiler.

Comment: I meant an overload on MyExpando.TrySetMember (not an override on ExpandoObject.TrySetMember)...

Comment: Your comment says something different from the `override` keyword in your code.

Comment: The `TrySetMember` method is called by the runtime binder, not by user.